# Finding eigenvalues in terms of $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hey guys I need some help with finding the eigenvalues of the following matrix








\begin{bmatrix}1&k\\ 2 &1 \end{bmatrix}

I have found till the determinant step but I am stuck here

$$(1-λ)(1-λ)-2k=0$$
$$λ^2-2λ+(1-2k)=0$$

How can I further proceed

Comment: Solve the quadratics for lambda.

Comment: You have been around for three months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the resulting polynomial of degree $2$, but that is not necessary.  You already have $(1-\lambda)^2 - 2k = 0$ hence
$$(1-\lambda)^2 = 2k$$

If $k$ is a positive real number, you'll get $1 - \lambda = \pm \sqrt{2k}$. Your eigenvalues are hence $\lambda_1 = 1 + \sqrt{2k}$ and $\lambda_2 = 1 - \sqrt{2k}$.